# Firebase RemoveObserver methods does not remove observer

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am observing a value until user logs out. But when I call

```
self.ref.removeObserver(withHandle: self.handle)
self.ref.removeAllObservers()
```

Both of them does not work. I am using the one at a time.

How can I remove the observer on Firebase Database Ref?

BR,

Erdem

Comment: where are you calling this function? in which method?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I am calling this function in my custom method. Do I need to call it somewhere special?

Comment: Try this code inside `viewDidDisappear` method of your viewcontroller

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I have called that method inside my singleton class but no success, on the other hand, I have called in viewDidDisappear as you told, it seems OK. Thank you. I am not sure Is it a bug or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I think your `ref` is not being made right since you are calling this function in your custom method. You should call it in `viewDidDisappear` method of your viewcontroller

According to the Firebase site

> You should remove listeners or observers in `viewDidDisappear` method
>
> If your controller is still syncing data when the view has
>   disappeared, you are wasting bandwidth and memory

Learn more here https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/best-practices-for-ios-uiviewcontroller_6.html